# Advance querying in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails Application that is having `User` ,`Role` , `Group` models.

User Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

Role Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Group Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I have also created a mapping tables like,

`roles_users` and `groups_users`  for mapping their id

So here each user can have multiple groups ans roles ,

in my role model there is only three entries,

`admin` with id `1`,
`trainer` with id `2`,
`trainee` with id `3`

i want to find all users under a particular group with role id = 3,

i have done like this,

```
@group = Group.find(2)
@users = @group.users
```

here i am getting all users under group `id =2` ,but i want to filter it again with role `id = 3`. How to fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@group = Group.find(2)
@users = @group.users.joins(:roles).where("roles.id = ? && users.age = ?",3,30)
```

Comment: It Works fine ....is it possible for me to add more condition here ie: Filter above result with age = 30 in users table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `@group.users.joins(:roles).where(roles: { id: 3 })`